# How to create a channel in a category with discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am making a discord bot and want to create a channel in a category that is just created by the bot. So i need to get the category ID and add the channel to it. But I cannot just get the id by hand since the channel and category are created with the same command.

I have tried some code to catch the id by name but I kept giving errors. And the code was wrong anyway.

So how can I get the ID from a channel and add a channel to it.

This is how I create a category and a bit later in the command I add the channel. How can I grab the id of the category

`await ctx.guild.create_category("bot commands")`

Comment: “I keep getting errors” is so vague. Please elaborate. Thank you.

Comment: I am sorry if it was vague. I understand I should have showed one of the errors or anything in that direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Guild.create_category`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.create_category) returns the category that was created. You can assign it to a temporary variable and then proceed to pass it to [`Guild.create_text_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.create_text_channel) as the `category`-argument like so:

```py
new_category = await ctx.guild.create_category("bot commands")
new_channel = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel("my channel name", category=new_category)
```

This will create a channel named "my channel name" in the newly created "bot commands" category